# R optional arguments for S4 setMethod

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I am interested in setting new methods for generic functions.  For example, let's say I have a new class (e.g. `coolClass`).  I could write a wrapper to calculate the `log10` of that class and easily set the method with the following code:

```
setMethod("Math", c(x="coolClass"),
          function(x)
          {
            op = .Generic[[1]]
            switch(op,
                   `log10` = log10_for_coolClass(x),
                   stop("Undefined operation")
            )
          }
)
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to set a method to pass multiple arguments.  For example, the generic `log` method.  Running `getGeneric("log")` shows the following:

```
> getGeneric("log")
standardGeneric for "log" defined from package "base"
  belonging to group(s): Math 

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("log", .Primitive("log"))
<bytecode: 0x2f9a958>
<environment: 0x2f937f0>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("log")  for currently available ones.
```

Seeing this, I would expect I could write the following to be able to pass the optional `base` argument.

```
setMethod("Math", signature(x="coolClass",...),
          function(x, ...)
          {
            op = .Generic[[1]]
            switch(op,
                   `log` = log_for_coolClass(x, ...),
                   stop("Undefined operation")
            )
          }
)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in matchSignature(signature, fdef, where) : 
  '...' used in an incorrect context
```

Tried without `...` in the `signature` I get a different error:

```
Error in rematchDefinition(definition, fdef, mnames, fnames, signature) : 
   methods can add arguments to the generic ‘Math’ only if '...' is an argument to the generic
```

Which seems strange to me given that `getGeneric` log shows the `...` in the method.

Any ideas?  Is there a way to capture additional arguments?  I am trying to become more comfortable with S4 methods but I am confused about how to pass optional arguments.  If this is not possible, I would appreciate it if someone could explain how the `log` function does work, for example, given that the function is part of the `Math` group but accepts multiple arguments.

## **Update**

Curiously, as noted below, I can use `setMethod` directly on `log` with the following:

```
setMethod("log", signature(x="big.matrix"),
          function(x, base=exp(1))
            {
            log_for_coolClass(x, base=base)
          }
          )
```

However, this doesn't quite pacify my curiosity.  For example, it seems strange to be so repetitive in code if I creating many new methods within the `Math` group.  Ideally it would look something like this:

```
setMethod("Math", c(x="coolClass"),
          function(x, base=exp(1))
          {
            op = .Generic[[1]]
            switch(op,
                   `log10` = log10_for_coolClass(x),
                   `log` = log_for_coolClass(x, base=base),
                   stop("Undefined operation")
            )
          }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a class

```
.A <- setClass("A", representation(x="numeric"))
```

For a function like `log` we have

```
> getGeneric("log")
standardGeneric for "log" defined from package "base"
  belonging to group(s): Math 

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("log", .Primitive("log"))
<bytecode: 0x2b41b28>
<environment: 0x2b39df8>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("log")  for currently available ones.
```

where the signature includes `...`. So we write

```
setMethod("log", "A", function(x, ...) {
    log(x@x, ...)
})
```

and have success

```
> log(.A(x=c(1, 2, NA)))
[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472        NA
> log(.A(x=c(1, 2, NA)), base=2)
[1]  0  1 NA
```

Next up: log10

```
> getGeneric("log10")
standardGeneric for "log10" defined from package "base"
  belonging to group(s): Math 

function (x) 
standardGeneric("log10", .Primitive("log10"))
<bytecode: 0x2b4a700>
<environment: 0x2b43138>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("log10")  for currently available ones.
```

No `...` arguments in the generic, so we're basically stuck -- write our own generic and implement methods that do include `...`, or write a log10,A-method that does not have `...` argument.

The same principle with respect to `...` applies to group generics -- the Math group generic doesn't have dots

```
> getGeneric("Math")
groupGenericFunction for "Math" defined from package "base"

function (x) 
standardGeneric("Math")
<bytecode: 0x2771d40>
<environment: 0x275ee20>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("Math")  for currently available ones.
```

so our method (implementing *all* Math operations, not just log; note that we don't typically reference .Generic explicitly) on objects of our class might be

```
setMethod("Math", "A", function(x) {
    callGeneric(x@x)
})
```

and now we have methods for all the Math functions, e.g.,

```
> sqrt(.A(x=1:4))
[1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000
```

also, our variant of log, accepting ..., is still available, so we can both define behavior of our class for all Math generics, and provide specialized implementations for specific generics.

There is probably a bug in the implementation of these group generics that should be addressed. If in a new session we defined our class and `Math` generic, but not the `log` function with `...` argument, we can still invoke

```
> log(.A(x=1:4))
[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123 1.3862944
> log(.A(x=1:4), base=2)
[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123 1.3862944
```

where the second argument is ignored but should really cause an error.

Comment: Your answer came just as I discovered the `setMethod` directly on `log`.  It is interesting to access all Math operations with `callGeneric` but my class requires more complex functions that I write separately and must call.  As such, it appears I must set certain methods separately.  I was hoping to be more concise (see updated question) but if that is the only way.